# Listview DeleteButton onclick broken?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I don't know if I'm just being stupid but I can't get bloody Javascript in my asp buttons onclick event :(

```
  <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" onclick="Javascript:returnConf();" />
```

I've tried variations including things like:

```
 <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" onclick="<%= GetMyStupidCode() %>" />
```

but the compiler keeps picking it up as code it should interpret or something and gives me errors such as:

```
Identifier expected

Invalid expression term )

Missing )
```

I'm lost, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What javascript function are you trying to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('This will delete the user permanently. Are you sure?');"
```

Comment: OnClientClick="return confirm('This will delete the user permanently. Are you sure?');" It's been a long day -.-